# Having issue sharing my Websites post to Facebook's timeline

Tags: facebook, facebook-timeline, facebook-wall

We want users to be able to post to their Facebook if they want to. We have it kind of working with the older Facebook profile but not with the new Timeline.

We want it to be like Tumblr where you can post/share to your Facebook account as much as you want.

Is there a limit of post that we can have a day per users or the via entire API in general?

We are using FB connect already of course!

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for Facebook's [Open Graph](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/) is probably the best place to start. Take a look at their [best practices](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/best-practices/) page, as well:

> If your application is making too many calls, the API server might rate limit you automatically, returning an "API_EC_TOO_MANY_CALLS" error.